# Rigol Waveform Viewer Alternative for Ubuntu

Tags: graphics

Can anyone please tell me that which tool is the Alternative of Rigol Waveform Viewer?

Comment: That doesn't turn up any matching results.

Comment: @ Zacharee1 Then what should i use to observe the digital oscilloscope wave?

Comment: I mean, that program doesn't exist. Google finds nothing on it.

Comment: it can be searched with the name of WFM viewer. here is the link of this software for windows"https://sourceforge.net/projects/wfmreader/"

Comment: http://hackaday.com/2013/03/25/rigol-wfm-viewer-ported-for-non-windows-users/?

Comment: I already checked this link but I was unable to get their point.

Comment: It leads to http://www.blaicher.com/2013/03/rigol-oscilloscope-binary-file-parser/

Comment: yup exactly, but there is no download link or something like that.

Comment: Scroll down to the giant letters that say "Get It"

Comment: it is providing me different codes on its different options.

Comment: what to do about those codes?

Comment: It gives you examples.

Comment: So what do i need to do here?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know what you're trying to do, and I don't know how to use that app, because I don't have a Rigol.

Comment: any waveform taken from digital oscilloscope can be observed using WFM viewer. it generates .csv file which can be used in matlab. i want to do same thing in Ubuntu.

Comment: Read the example. It tells you exactly how to do that.

Comment: I think its telling that how to do it in python?

Comment: those are Python scripts, so yes.

Comment: But i dont want to make it so complex, there must be a software which can read .wfm file of oscilloscope and create .csv file. I used WFM in windows on same principle.